# R data frame: Create weighted average group-wise

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, weighted-average

I'm working on an R dataframe

with columns
`GROUP_COL | TIME| VALUE`

. Time is in order, value is numerical and group col is a categorical variable I want to group the data by.
My goal is to

- first group by the `GROUP_COL` variable
- then, order by `TIME`
- and then calculate a weighted mean for the values in each group using the formula `value = 0.1 * previous_value + 0.9 * value` for each row. If there is no previous value, leave the value as it is.
- this weighted value should be stored in a separate column `WEIGHTED`.

What I tried so far is: Usng `dplyr, I created a vector of previous values using lag()

```
weighted_avg_with_previous <- function(.data, lag_weight=0.1) {
  # get previous values
  lag_val <- lag(.data$VALUE, n = 1L, default = 0, order_by = .data$TIME)

  # give each value a weight 0.9 for current value and 0.1 for previous value
  weighted = (1 -lag_weight) * .data$VALUE + lag_weight * lag_val
  return (weighted)
}

data <- data %>% 
  group_by(SALES_RESPONSIBILITY, PRODUCT_AREA, CURRENCY, FORECAST_TYPE) %>% 
  arrange(HORIZON, .by_group=TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(WEIGHTED_VALUE = weighted_avg_with_previous(0.1))
```

However, the `mutate` statement throws an error. How can I get my `weighted_avg_with_previous` functions to run on the single groups?

Example:

```
    GROUP | TIME| VALUE | WEIGHTED VALUE
    _____________________________________
     A    |  1  |   1   |     1
     A    |  2  |   2   |     1.9
     A    |  3  |   3   |     2.9
     A    |  4  |   4   |     3.9
     B    |  1  |   3   |     3
     B    |  2  |   7   |     6.6
     B    |  3  |   -4  |     -3.3
     ...
```

Best,
Julia

Answer (score 3):

```
library(tidyverse)    
df <- structure(list(GROUP = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"),
    TIME = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L), VALUE = c(1L, 2L, 3L,
    4L, 3L, 7L, -4L)), row.names = c(NA, -7L),  class = c("tbl_df",
"tbl", "data.frame"))


 df %>%
      group_by(GROUP) %>%
      mutate(previous.value = lag(VALUE)) %>%
      mutate(weighted.value = ifelse(is.na(previous.value),VALUE, 0.1*previous.value + 0.9*VALUE)) %>%
      select(-previous.value)
```

The first `mutate()` statement creates a new variable for lagged `value` and the second one creates `weighted.value` which equals either `0.1*previous.value + 0.9*value`, or `value` if `previous.value` is null.

Output:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 4
# Groups:   GROUP [2]
  GROUP  TIME VALUE weighted.value
  <chr> <int> <int>          <dbl>
1 A         1     1            1
2 A         2     2            1.9
3 A         3     3            2.9
4 A         4     4            3.9
5 B         1     3            3
6 B         2     7            6.6
7 B         3    -4           -2.9
```